# upgrading rails 3 to 3.1 - ajax requests not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery, asset-pipeline

I originally needed to set the ajax beforeSend to include the csrf meta tags for all ajax post requests (the session was getting reset, big pain, etc).  This got post requests working fine.  However this seems like something that should have been taken care of in the latest version of jquery-rails.  I feel like I missed something when I upgraded...and yes, I am including the csrf meta tag in my layout.

Now my issue is link_to :remote.  My links are generating the correct html:

```
    <%=link_to( "important", "/questions/importance?qid=#{q.id}&imp=up", 
:method=>"post",:remote=>true)%>
```

generates:

```
    <a rel="nofollow" data-remote="true" data-method="post" 
href="/questions/importance?qid=30&amp;imp=up">important</a>
```

However, when clicked the request is a GET request and is not an xhr request / doesn't use my js handlers.  This did work fine before upgrading to 3.1.3 from 3.0.7

Request that is generated:

```
Started GET "/questions/importance?qid=30&imp=up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-30 11:41:36 -0500
Creating scope :page. Overwriting existing method Question.page.
  Processing by QuestionsController#importance as HTML
  Parameters: {"qid"=>"30", "imp"=>"up"}
```

Here's the relavent parts of my layout:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
    <%= yield :javascript %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
      var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);
    });
    </script>
```

Any insight into this? Did I miss something when upgrading?

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery.purr
//= require best_in_place
//= require fancybox
//= require_tree .
```

javascript  files that are being included (via page source):

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.purr.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/best_in_place.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.fancybox.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/fancybox.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/autocomplete-rails.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.validate.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/validators.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="26P9UWaXFsZBE6jfjkQv00GgS+7+XmOOPxlh55liz4Q=" name="csrf-token" />
```

Comment: What's in your application.js ? Are you loading jquery and jquery_ujs ?

Comment: updating question with application.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `jquery_ujs` for the data-method attributes rails creates to actually be used. Assuming you have the jquery_ujs gem in your app, adding

```
//= require jquery_ujs
```

To application.js (after jquery is loaded) should fix things